# Silence errors from colorscheme, silent! and try/catch not working

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I modified a colorscheme file which generates E419/E420 errors when loading, but I would like to ignore them silently. `silent!` and `try`/`catch` aren't working for me.

My .vimrc is shown below. All the loading of the "theme" is done at `source ~/.vim/theme.vim`.

### .vimrc

```
set backspace=2

set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set expandtab
set smarttab

:au FileType cpp setlocal tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2 cindent
:au FileType tcl setlocal tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2
:au FileType make setlocal noexpandtab

source ~/.vim/theme.vim                                                                                                                                                                                             

set cursorline
set hlsearch
set showmatch
set matchtime=0
syntax enable

set number
set relativenumber
nmap <F3> :set nu! rnu!<CR>

nnoremap Q <nop>

" *last-position-jump*
:au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g`\"" | endif
```

### Attempt 1: ~/.vim/theme.vim

```
set t_Co=256
let g:gruvbox_termcolors=16
set background=dark
silent! colorscheme gruvbox
```

Using `silent!` I still get these errors whenever I start vim:

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>3_HL:
line   43:
E419: FG color unknown
E420: BG color unknown
E420: BG color unknown
E420: BG color unknown
E419: FG color unknown
E419: FG color unknown
E419: FG color unknown
E419: FG color unknown
E419: FG color unknown
E419: FG color unknown
E419: FG color unknown
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

### Attempt 2: ~/.vim/theme.vim

```
set t_Co=256
let g:gruvbox_termcolors=16
set background=dark
try
    colorscheme gruvbox
catch
endtry
```

Using `try`/`catch`, I still get the same errors as above.

### Attempt 3: ~/.vimrc

I also tried the same techniques directly in my ~/.vimrc, wrapping them around the source command, but I still get the same errors.

```
silent! source ~/.vim/theme.vim
```

```
try
    source ~/.vim/theme.vim
catch
endtry
```

How can I silence these errors every time I launch vim?

### vim --version output

```
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Oct  7 2016 22:47:41)
Included patches: 1-2
Compiled by ...
Huge version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
+arabic          +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
+autocmd         +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tcl
+balloon_eval    +folding         +mouse_xterm     +termguicolors
+browse          -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
++builtin_terms  +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+byte_offset     +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
+channel         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +timers
+cindent         +iconv           +num64           +title
+clientserver    +insert_expand   +packages        +toolbar
+clipboard       +job             +path_extra      +user_commands
+cmdline_compl   +jumplist        -perl            +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist    +keymap          +persistent_undo +virtualedit
+cmdline_info    +lambda          +postscript      +visual
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visualextra
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +viminfo
+cryptv          +linebreak       -python          +vreplace
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +wildignore
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildmenu
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +windows
+dialog_con_gui  -lua             +rightleft       +writebackup
+diff            +menu            -ruby            +X11
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -xfontset
+dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           +xim
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     +xpm
+emacs_tags      +mouseshape      +startuptime     +xsmp_interact
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      +xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax          
+farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary   
...
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12     -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim   -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lcairo -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lglib-2.0   -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE  -lm -ltinfo -lelf -lnsl  -lselinux -lacl -lattr
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `syntax enable` reloads your current color scheme.  This is documented at `:help syntax-loading`.  If there is an error in the colors file, you'll see it then.  Options:

1. Move `syntax enable` to before the `colorscheme` statement.  This makes the most sense- you should be enabling syntax highlighting before loading color schemes.
2. Use `silent! syntax enable` (or try/catch).